# How do I call update action from another action in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm writing a basic member modifying action, and I figured, lets stay DRY and just modify the params hash then pass along to our `update` method but it doesn't seem to work. I guess there is some rails magic going on that I can't find... From what I've read this should work. I'm using Rails 3.2.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
  # POST /tasks/1/toggle_done
  def toggle_done
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    puts "<<<<<", params

    # invert done bool value
    params[:done] = !(@task.done)

    # thought maybe update_attributes retured a full set of 
    # attributes in the params...
    #params[:name] = @task.name + "...test."

    # thought maybe the method call to update was getting 
    # filtered or something. Doesn't seem to help.
    #params[:_method] = "put"
    # redirect to update with these new params

    puts ">>>>>", params

    # Why bother rewriting task.done = x; task.save; 
    # redirect_to show; etc when update already does that.
    update
  end

  # PUT /tasks/1
  # PUT /tasks/1.json
  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    puts "======", params

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I get the following console output:

```
<<<<<
{"_method"=>"post", "authenticity_token"=>"CVqzsJfSVgM7Bq/kXlrjzkWVoA7Pbne4GNEHqbQB42s=", "action"=>"toggle_done", "controller"=>"tasks", "id"=>"1"}
>>>>>
{"_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"CVqzsJfSVgM7Bq/kXlrjzkWVoA7Pbne4GNEHqbQB42s=", "action"=>"toggle_done", "controller"=>"tasks", "id"=>"1", "done"=>false, "name"=>"Put Done button in index view...test."}
======
{"_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"CVqzsJfSVgM7Bq/kXlrjzkWVoA7Pbne4GNEHqbQB42s=", "action"=>"toggle_done", "controller"=>"tasks", "id"=>"1", "done"=>false, "name"=>"Put Done button in index view...test."}
```

So it seems like the params array is set right. It renders the regular `show` view with the flash message "Task was successfully updated.", so it seems like the whole method gets executed but non of the model properties are getting changed. I guess something inside update_attributes is failing. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Also is this a crazy thing to do? Should I be setting and saving inside my toggle_done method instead of chaining to update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails saves the attributes for the task object in the hash `params[:task]`. So you in your `toggle_done` method you need to save the result in `params[:task][:done]` otherwise rails cannot associate the `done` attribute with the task.

```
def toggle_done
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  params[:task] = { done: !(@task.done) }
  update
end
```

But with calling the update method you make 3 database queries where only 2 are neccessary - And the first 2 are identically because you load the Task with the ID in the `toggle_done` method as well as in `update`.

To avoid this you can put the save and redirect part into a protected method and call it when you want to save it. Like this:

```
def toggle_done
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  params[:task] =  { done: !(@task.done) }
  save_updated
end

def update
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  save_updated
end

protected
def save_updated
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing params[:task] to update_attributes, which doesn't exist.  Try:

```
params[:task] = {:done => !(@task.done)}
```

Comment: Doh. Obviously not paying enough attention. I guess my question still stands, is it a legitimate "rails way" to do that?

Comment: I guess it is just to do it like you did, but as I pointed out in my answer, you are making more database requests then necessary.

Comment: So the rails DRY way is to put common code into own methods and call those instead...